# Search bar not showing in header on Magento site

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a Magento site, and for some reason the search bar is not showing up in the header. I've looked at the header template file, and this line is still there:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch')
```

I've also checked to see if the search is enabled in admin by going to `System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`

And `Mage_CatalogSearch` is enabled.

Any ideas as to why the search bar has disappeared from the header?

Thanks

Comment: Check in your layout XML that a block named topSearch is located within <reference name="header"></reference> - by default it is in catalogsearch.xml - in some themes it'sbrought out in topContainer I believe.

Comment: Also i would look at the Header section of the CSS

Comment: Yeah, its in there <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the html that is being created? It may be being hidden by CSS - which I have seen before

Comment: http://dirtballfashion.com/ this is the site if it helps. Doesn't seem to be hidden by the CSS

Answer (score 0):

check your code...I suppose it should be

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('top.search')
```

and not this

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch')
```

Comment: Nice. Do you think he was waiting 10 years for your answer.